# Submit Form after Calling getJSON in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms, getjson

I have the form:

```
$('#ambition_submit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var output = getTimelineEntryData(data.toJSON());//console.log(output);
    $.getJSON('http://www.x.com/x/api/add_subgoals.php',{action:'add.subgoals',ambition_id:ambition_id,subgoals:output}, function (response) {
        //var this_url = this.url; console.log(this_url);
        if (response.status == 200) {
            var result = response.message;//alert(response.message);
            $('#form_content').submit();
            $('form[name=testing747]').submit();//console.log('Test ' + $('form[name=testing747]').length);
        }
        else{
            alert(response.message);
        }
    });
});
```

On submit I want the ajax to run and on completion, the form to submit. How can I get the form to definitely submit whatever the outcome of the ajax is?

Thanks

Comment: So you are submitting two forms at same time.

Comment: @Jai No, I just wanted to show what I have already tried. They are both directed at the same form.

Comment: is '#ambition_submit' an input type="submit" ? if yes change it to a regular button, so when you .submit() the form it wont prevent default behaviour

Comment: @Chris you can use `.always()` callback which works for both **success or error**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is the question:

> How can I get the form to definitely submit whatever the outcome of the ajax is?

For this you can use `.always()` which works for ***`both success and error`*** method to chain your ajax like:

```
  $('#ambition_submit').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var output = getTimelineEntryData(data.toJSON()); //console.log(output);
      $.getJSON('http://www.x.com/x/api/add_subgoals.php', {
          action: 'add.subgoals',
          ambition_id: ambition_id,
          subgoals: output
      }, function (response) {
          //var this_url = this.url; console.log(this_url);
          if (response.status == 200) {
              var result = response.message; //alert(response.message);
          } else {
              alert(response.message);
          }
      }).always(function () {
          $('#form_content').submit();
          $('form[name=testing747]').submit(); //console.log('Test ' + $('form[name=testing747]').length);
      });
  });
```